# Open CTI - JS error unable to call

Tags: javascript, opencti, aws

I have install and configure the salesforce package (Amazon Connect - Universal Package).

Everything looks fine, when using the CTI dialer. I am able to make phone calls. However, when I click in the phone icon, the dialer doesnt work. I get a Javascript error:

> Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-EcwaM0KV0B3Zx5NUYmA2xbJLMjpPhKRc' chrome-extension: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.canary.lwc.dev *.vf.force.com blob: [https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/"](https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/%22). Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.

[image]

I am not sure if there is something that I am missing in the CTI config, or this is just a browser issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with a workaround:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KRaQQAW&title=click-to-dial-not-working-from-phone-mobile-menu-items-in-collapsible-highlight-panel-of-record-detail-page-in-lex

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you. I am fairly new to StackExchange and still learning best practices.